# Unable to return a list in Python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary

I am trying a question from leetcode which is like this.

Given an array of integer nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to the target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

You can return the answer in any order.

```
Example 1:

Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Explanation: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
```

My **solution** is like this:

```
def xyz(list_1, result):
    dict_1 = dict()
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        num = list_1[i]
        compliment = result - num
        print(compliment)

        if num in dict_1:
            print(dict_1)
            # breakpoint()
            # abc = [i,dict_1[compliment]]
            return [i, dict_1[compliment]]
        else:

            dict_1[compliment] = i
            print(dict_1)


list_1 = [2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11]
result = 5
final = xyz(list_1, result)
print(final)
```

But when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
File "E:/Leetcode_Python/sumtarget.py", line 19, in xyz
    return [i, dict_1[compliment]]
KeyError: 2
```

I dont understand why I cannot return the list. What is wrong here??

**Updates:**

```
def xyz(list_1,result):
    
    dict_1 = dict()
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        num = list_1[i]
        compliment = result - num
        # print(compliment)        
        
        if compliment in dict_1:
            print(compliment)
            print(dict_1[compliment])            
            return [i,dict_1[compliment]]
        else:
            
            dict_1[num] = i
            # print(dict_1)
            

list_1 = [2,3,6,8,9,11]
result = 19
final = xyz(list_1,result)
print(final)
```

I tried with the above code and it worked. I am surprised. I just started looking for compliment and start adding number. But isnt it the same as adding compliment and start looking for num??

Comment: `dict_1` is an empty dictionary (you are not putting any values in it), and then you are trying to access the value with key `compliment`, which doesn't exist, which is why you are getting the `KeyError` error.

Answer (score 1):

1. If `compliment` is not found, then you're supposed to insert `num` into the dictionary
2. Instead of checking for `num`, you need to check the occurrence of `compliment` in the dictionary.

```py
def xyz(list_1, result):
    dict_1 = dict()
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        num = list_1[i]
        compliment = result - num

        if compliment in dict_1:
            return [i, dict_1[compliment]]
        else:
            dict_1[num] = i

list_1 = [2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11]
result = 5
final = xyz(list_1, result)
print(final)
```

Edit: this approach is easier to understand; adding `num` and then searching for `compliment`. However, like the comment suggests, it can also be done the other way round, like the OP has attempted. The issue is `return [i, dict_1[compliment]]`, which should be replaced by `return [i, dict_1[num]]`.

Comment: I added the code as you said above. I am surprised. I just started looking for compliment and start adding number. But isnt it the same as adding compliment and start looking for num??